# SwiftUi CloudKit Record Modify Failed to Save "WRITE operation not permitted"

Tags: database, swiftui, permissions, cloudkit

I cant seem to get certain records to modify in my public database. The error is

> Error saving record <CKRecordID: XXXXXXX; recordName=XXXXXX, zoneID=_defaultZone:**defaultOwner**> to server: WRITE operation not permitted

I don't understand why it says "Write not permitted" because I have all the correct Security Roles checked off in the dashboard. I also confirmed that it is signed into Icloud before I try to modify the record.

This is the relevant code:

```
// MARK: - Modify Updates in Cloudkit
static func modifyUpdates(item: pushNote, completion: @escaping (Result<pushNote, Error>) ->
    ()) {
    guard let recordID = item.recordID else { return }
    CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { (record, err) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let err = err {
                completion(.failure(err))
                return
            }
            guard let record = record else { return }
            
            
            record["updates"] = item.updates as CKRecordValue
            
            CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.save(record) { (record, err) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let err = err {
                        completion(.failure(err))
                        return
                    }
                    guard let record = record else { return }
                    let id = record.recordID
                    guard let updts = record["updates"] as? [String] else { return }
                    guard let boss = record["bossID"] as? String else { return }
                    
                    let element = pushNote(recordID:id, bossID: boss, updates : updts)
                    completion(.success(element))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving Security Role changes takes time to kick it. Like 10min for me. I recommend not clicking Save too many times. Log out and back in to see if it is actually saved.